# HIbernate one-to-one annotation isn't generating foreign key GerericGenerator in dependent table

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, postgresql, jpa-2.1

I am trying to create OneToOne relation between a Person and Auth table. The problem is when the DB table "Auth" is generated, I'm not seeing the foreign key in the AUTH table that should reference Person. The object is to have the Auth table use the same Primary Key of the Person Table.

```
 @MappedSuperclass
 public abstract class DomainBase {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE) 
    private Long id;

    @Version
    @Column(name="OPLOCK")
    private Integer version;
 }


 @Entity
 @Table(name = "person")  
 public class Person extends DomainBase {
        @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
            @JoinColumn(name="auth_id")
        private Auth auth;
 }


 @Entity
 public class Auth {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator="foreign")
    @GenericGenerator(name="foreign", strategy = "foreign", parameters={
      @Parameter(name="property", value="person")
    })
    @Column(name="person_id")
    private int personId;
    ---------------------------------

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn 
    private Person person;
 }
```

My Database scripts after hibernate DB generation.

```
 CREATE TABLE auth
 (
   person_id integer NOT NULL,
   activate boolean,
   activationid character varying(255),
   last_login_attempt_date timestamp without time zone,
   last_login_attempt_timezone character varying(255),
   last_login_date timestamp without time zone,
   last_login_timezone character varying(255),
   nonlocked boolean,
   num_login_attempts integer,
   CONSTRAINT auth_pkey PRIMARY KEY (person_id),
   CONSTRAINT uk_d68auh3xsosyrjw3vmwseawvt UNIQUE (activationid)
 )
 WITH (
   OIDS=FALSE
 );
 ALTER TABLE auth
   OWNER TO postgres;
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the problem is you declare twice the @OneToOne annotation between "person" table and "auth" table, without specify the relation between them. Take a look at the [hibernate documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/), at the point 2.2.5.1, there is some examples about using one-to-one association.

For me, the best way is to set up the association in one table, the one that declare the foreing key column, and to use the `mappedBy` parameter in the other object. In your code, this will be :

```
 @Entity
 @Table(name = "person")  
 public class Person extends DomainBase {
     @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
     @JoinColumn(name="auth_id")
     private Auth auth;
 }


 @Entity
 public class Auth {
     @Id
     @GeneratedValue(generator="foreign")
     @GenericGenerator(name="foreign", strategy = "foreign", parameters={
         @Parameter(name="property", value="person")
     })
     @Column(name="person_id")
     private int personId;

     @OneToOne(mappedBy = "auth")
     private Person person;
....
 }
```

This is the second example in the hibernate documentation, introduce just after the sentence "In the following example, the associated entities are linked through an explicit foreign key column". I tested this code, and the "auth_id" column appeared.

Comment: the hibernate documentation is lacking. What makes a onetoone into a shared primary key? From the docs you shown, I don't see what makes it be. Can you explain?

Comment: By "shared primary keys", i just mean using the id of a table like a foreign key in an other table, to allow the relation between them. I should have not used the term "shared". I edit my answer

Comment: With that configuration, I am getting this error -> attempted to assign id from null one-to-one property [XXXXX.domains.Auth.person] when attempting to do this [link](http://pastie.org/9315522)

Comment: When you set an auth for a person, auth must have an id. In order to realize this, create a auth, save it, get it and then associate it with a person object. In concrete terms, add `Auth authSaved = this.authRepository.save(auth)` between line 3 and line 4. It's possible that you need to change your Generated Value strategy for the auth id. If it's the case, use `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)` instead of both `@GeneratedValue` and `@GenericGenerator` annotations, it should be work.

Comment: thought that was the purpose of using Shared Primary Key. As in the owner would would share it persisted primary key tot he dependent and in return the dependent would use that value as it's own primary key.

Comment: @EPerrin95 You have no clue how much I have looked for this. Thanks a lot.